# Cross Filter Disabled For Report with Master Detail Custom Report Type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, cross-filter

We have a custom report that uses a custom report type but when we try to add a cross filter on the report the option is greyed out / disabled.

The custom report type has a relationship from Opportunity (primary object) to a custom object (with or without related records).  It would appear that this type of relationship should allow cross filters as we have achieved it with similar reports / report types.

Thanks
Stef

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be caused by the the Opportunity ID field being omitted from the Selected Fields in the custom report type.  When the Opportunity ID was added to the custom report type the Cross Filter option was enabled again.